# Informal derivation (and interpretation) of Substitution Rule from Chain Rule?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, substitution, chain-rule

The **Chain Rule** may be stated informally as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}\overset{1}{=}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$

Informal/intuitive interpretation:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\text{The change in }z\text{ caused by}\\
\text{a small unit change in }x
\end{array}\overset{2}{=}\begin{array}{c}
\text{The change in }z\text{ caused by}\\
\text{a small unit change in }y
\end{array}\times\begin{array}{c}
\text{The change in }y\text{ caused by}\\
\text{a small unit change in }x.
\end{array}$$

---

The **Substitution Rule** (integration) is the inverse/counterpart of the Chain Rule.

- How might we derive (even if only informally) the Substitution Rule from $\overset{1}{=}$?
- Is there an informal and intuitive interpretation of the Substitution Rule (similar to $\overset{2}{=}$ for the Chain Rule)?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932053/proof-of-the-substitution-rule-for-integrals-for-the-indefinite-case and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integration_by_Substitution#Proof_for_Indefinite_Integrals

Comment: the expression $$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}\overset{1}{=}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ is completely formal if we assume that $z$ is a function of $y$ and $y$ is a function of $x$. It is the same that write $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g'$

Answer (score 0):

Informally, you might think of the substitution rule this way:

\begin{align}
&\begin{array}{c}\text{the accumulated}\\ \text{value due to}
\\ \text{integration of}\end{array}
\left( \begin{array}{c}\text{the rate of}\\ \text{accumulation per}\\
 \text{unit change in $x$}\end{array} \times
\begin{array}{c}\text{the small}\\ \text{change}\\ 
\text{in $x$}\end{array} \right)\\[2ex]
&\qquad = 
\begin{array}{c}\text{the accumulated}\\ \text{value due to}
\\ \text{integration of}\end{array}\left( 
\begin{array}{c}\text{the rate of}\\ \text{accumulation per}\\
 \text{unit change in $u$}\end{array} \times
\begin{array}{c}\text{the change in $u$}\\ \text{causedby a small}
\\ \text{change in $x$}\end{array}  \times
\begin{array}{c}\text{the small}\\ \text{change}\\ 
\text{in $x$}\end{array} \right)\\[2ex]
&\qquad = 
\begin{array}{c}\text{the accumulated}\\ \text{value due to}
\\ \text{integration of}\end{array}\left( 
\begin{array}{c}\text{the rate of}\\ \text{accumulation per}\\
 \text{unit change in $u$}\end{array} \times
\begin{array}{c}\text{the small}\\ \text{change}\\ 
\text{in $u$}\end{array} \right)\\[2ex]
\end{align}

When we write $\int f(x)\,dx = \int g(u)\, du$ the middle line is not explicitly included in the equation, but we invoke it implicitly when we write 
$f(x) = g(u) \frac{du}{dx}$ and $du = \frac{du}{dx} dx.$

Also implicitly assumed in all of this is that "the small change in $u$" is tied in a lockstep manner to "the small change in $x$" by defining $u$ as a function of $x$.
(That is why I wrote "the small change" rather than "a small change". You cannot have just any small change in each place; each small change must be *the* change that corresponds to the small changes that occur the other parts of the equation.)

The relationship between the chain rule and the substitution rule is evident here.