# Correct use of the Substitution Rule (or Integration by Substitution)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

When using the Substitution Rule (or Integration by Substitution), Stewart (*Calculus: Early Transcendentals*, 8e, 2016, p. 413) writes $$\int\sqrt{1+x^2}2x\,dx\overset{1}{=}\int\sqrt{u}\,du.$$

But strictly speaking, is $\overset{1}{=}$ correct?

I thought $u$ was just a dummy variable that can be replaced by any other letter, e.g. $x$. In which case, $$\int\sqrt{u}\,du=\int\sqrt{x}\,dx=\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}+C,$$ which is clearly not equal to $\int\sqrt{1+x^2}2x\,dx$.

And if $\overset{1}{=}$ is wrong, then what is the correct way to use the Substitution Rule?

Comment: You cannot substitute by the same variable given in the question. If you do that you are assuming $1+x^2=x$ which is absolutely not right.

Comment: Let $u=x^2+1$. Then, $du=2xdx$.

Comment: @tomriddle99: So you're saying that in general, the following statement is false? $$\int\sqrt{u}\,du=\int\sqrt{x}\,dx$$

Comment: The above statement is correct (as the variable on the right of the integration sign can be replaced by any letter). However, changing $u$ to $x$ doesn't make the integral any easier to solve. The author of textbook did not set $u=x$ to get the RHS of $(1)$. They choose $u=x^2+1$.

Answer (score 10):

$x$ is not a [dummy variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables), as that is an indefinite integral. You are likely thinking of definite integrals, in which case rewriting the integral using the same variable is fairly common, as it would indeed be a dummy variable:

$$\int_0^12x\sqrt{x^2+1}~\mathrm dx=\int_1^2\sqrt x~\mathrm dx$$

since the variables vanish after performing the integration. The same is not true for indefinite integrals, where the variable remains after integration:

$$\int2x\sqrt{x^2+1}~\mathrm dx=\frac23(x^2+1)^{3/2}+C_1=\frac23u^{3/2}+C_1=\int\sqrt u~\mathrm du\ne\int\sqrt x~\mathrm dx=\frac23x^{3/2}+C_2$$

where $u=x^2+1$.

Answer (score 3):

The thing about variables in places like this is you need to be careful to keep track of the scope of their definitions.

In a definite integral the scope of the variable of integration is strictly confined to the integrand. For example, in
$$ \int_0^\pi x^2 \sin(x)\, dx $$
the variable $x$ that occurs in the $dx$ is the same $x$ that is found in $x^2\sin(x),$ but a completely distinct variable from any other occurrence of the letter $x$ anywhere. You can even replace $\pi$ with $x$ at the upper limit of the integral and it (technically) is unrelated to the $x$ in the $dx.$

In an equation such as
$$ \int x^2 \, dx = \frac13 x^3 + C, \tag1$$
however, while the $x$ is a dummy variable in the sense that you could just as well write
$$ \int y^2 \, dy = \frac13 y^3 + C \tag2$$
without changing the fundamental meaning of the equation,
the scope of $x$ is not strictly limited to the integrand. 
It is closely related to (if not exactly the same as) the $x$ in $\frac13 x^3.$
After all, writing
$$ \int y^2 \, dy = \frac13 x^3 + C \tag3$$
(replacing $x$ with $y$ inside the integral but not elsewhere)
would not preserve the meaning of Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$;
in order to say the same thing as those equations do, you could give Equation $(3)$  *and* the stipulation that $y = x,$ but Equation $(3)$ by itself is not enough.

In short, when you use a dummy variable such as $x$ in writing an equation for the indefinite integral of a function, the scope of $x$ is not just the integrand within the integral; it's the entire equation. Hence
$$\int\sqrt{u}\,du = \int\sqrt{x}\,dx = \frac23 x^{3/2}+C $$
makes sense only if you stipulate that $u = x$; if you have in mind that $u = 1 + x^2$ then the first equality sign is not correct at all.

On the other hand, in a context where you have declared that $u = 1 + x^2,$ you can very well say that
$$\int\sqrt{u}\,du = \frac23 u^{3/2}+C,$$
and then, remembering that $u = 1 + x^2,$ you can substitute $1+x^2$ for the $u$ on the right-hand side.
You cannot just substitute $x$ for $u$ anywhere in that context, because then you would be mixing inconsistent relationships between $u$ and $x$:
implicitly saying that $u = 1 + x^2$ and $u = x$ at the same time.

---

For completness, I'll attempt to derive the substitution rule from the chain rule while taking proper care about notation.
The chain rule says that if $F(x) = G(u(x)),$ then

$$  F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} G(u(x)) = G'(u(x))\, u'(x). $$

(You might see $G'(u(x))$ written $\frac{dG}{du}$ and $u'(x)$ written 
$\frac{du}{dx},$ that is, in Leibniz notation, since that notation has some strong mnemonic properties in this usage.)

Therefore, given that $F(x) = G(u(x)),$
if we define a function $g = G',$
we have that $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of

\begin{align}
\int g(u(x))\, u'(x) \, dx 
&= \int G'(u(x))\, u'(x) \, dx \\
&= \int F'(x)\, dx \\
&= F(x) + C \\
&= G(u(x)) + C.
\end{align}

The substitution rule is really just an application of this formula.
In order to find $\int f(x)\,dx,$
we first guess functions $g$ and $u$ such that
$f(x) = g(u(x))\,u'(x)$ and such that $g$ has a known antiderivative $G.$
Then we can define $F(x) = G(u(x))$ and apply the equations above to show that

$$ \int f(x)\,dx = G(u(x)) + C. $$

In writing out the substitution rule, however, one often uses a convenient notation in which we write $u$ instead of $u(x)$ and $du$ instead of $u'(x) \, dx.$
In that form the rule is much easier to remember:

$$ \int f(x)\,dx = \int g(u)\,du = G(u) + C = F(x) + C. $$

(There is a way to make the substitution of $du$ for $u'(x) \, dx$ more than just a notational gimmick, but that would take a lot more development and for our purposes here I think the notational gimmick is enough.)

The important thing here is that we did not just rename the dummy variable $x$;
we introduced a *function* of $x$ named $u.$
Because of the chain rule, we are able to integrate $g(u(x))\, u'(x)$
(with respect to the original variable $x$)
using a known formula for the antiderivative of $g,$
obtaining a compound function $G(u(x)),$ which we can then write in a form
that more clearly shows it as a function of $x.$
Keeping a consistent relationship between our uses of the symbols
$u$ and $x$ is essential to this process.

---

Instead of (or in addition to) this attempt to prove the substitution rule, one could also look at the answers to [Proof of the substitution rule for integrals for the indefinite case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932053/proof-of-the-substitution-rule-for-integrals-for-the-indefinite-case)

Answer (score 1):

You are violating the [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) by:
$$\underbrace{\int\sqrt{1+x^2}2x\,dx}_{I_1}\overset{1}{=}\underbrace{\int\sqrt{u}\,du}_{I_2}=\underbrace{\int\sqrt{x}\,dx}_{I_3}.$$
If $I_1=I_2$ and $I_2=I_3$, then $I_1=I_3$, however, the last relation is obviously incorrect, consequently you can not claim $I_2=I_3$, because $u=1+x^2\ne x$.

In the Wikipedia article [Integration by substitution, Example 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Example_3:_antiderivatives), it is stated:

> An antiderivative for the substituted function can hopefully be determined; the original substitution between u and x is then undone.

So, you need to determine the antidervative of substituted function and then undo (i.e. return to $x$) the substitution between the $u$ and $x$.